# Why do I have 3 IP's and one FQDN?

Tags: linux, dns

I want to configure bind as private network DNS on Ubuntu 16.04.

With hostname I got

```
192.168.0.12 192.168.27.1 192.168.129.1
```

But

```
hostname

jholmes-System-Product-jh
```

My question is why do I have 3 values for IP and only one for domain Name?

Comment: These are all private IP addresses for your local network, and your host is probably part of at least 3 LAN network segments. Try to understand your network setup (which we can't guess unless you tell us something about it). BTW, if these are static addresses, you don't need to run `bind`; entries in `/etc/hosts` are enough.

Comment: What do you mean by "with hostname I got"?

Comment: @Barmar I do not understand why one host has three ip addr values.

Comment: How many NICs does it have? Each NIC needs an IP.

Comment: Please provide the output from `ifconfig` or the equivalent command for you system to display your network interfaces and there settings.